# Codeigniter 3 - Query Builder 'join' Method '!=' operator is not giving expected output

Tags: codeigniter, inner-join, codeigniter-3, query-builder, codeigniter-datamapper

**Not a Duplicate Question!!!**

---

I am using **CodeIgniter 3 - Query Builder Class** with **MySQLi**.

---

### Tables in DB:

'**category_level_1**'  Table:
[image]

'**category_level_2**' Table:
[image]

---

### Query in model.php:

```
$query = $this->db
  ->select('category_level_1.id, category_level_1.category')
  ->from('category_level_1')
  ->join('category_level_2', 'category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id != category_level_1.id', 'inner')
  ->group_by('category_level_1.id')
  ->get();
```

---

### Output :

[image]

 Inner-Join not working.

---

### Expected Output :

[image]

 Only need to output records in 'category_level_1' Table which are not related with 'category_level_2' Table.

---

### Issue:

As showed above, output values are not as expected according to '**!=**' operator is **not working** **with** **'inner' join**.

Comment: Just had a quick read of this, and although I'm not an SQL expert, joining tables using 'not equals' (!=) seems weird. I would use 'equal' (=) and put the condition `category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id != category_level_1.id` in a `where` clause.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that also.. But, output not as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try using a `left` or`right` `join` and a `where` clause. Give the following a go:

```
$query = $this->db
  ->select('category_level_1.id, category_level_1.category')
  ->from('category_level_1')
  ->join('category_level_2', 'category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id = category_level_1.id', 'left')
  ->where('category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id IS NULL')
  ->group_by('category_level_1.id')
  ->get();
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, category 
        FROM category_level_1
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT cat_lvl1_id FROM category_level_2)";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
print_r($query->result());
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 93
            [category] => dummy
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this way and let you know :)

Comment: It's working also. Thanks for your effort. That way is nice for who are not aware of CodeIgniter Query Builder Classs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db ->select('category_level_1.id, category_level_1.category') ->from('category_level_1') ->join('category_level_2', 'category_level_2.cat_lvl1_id <> category_level_1.id', 'inner') ->group_by('category_level_1.id') ->get();
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know :)